# Daily command cooldown | discord.py

Tags: discord.py

So, Currently I'm trynna make a cooldown where it displays the remaining time in hours and mins. I figured out mins and seconds but I'm stumped on hours. Here's my code

```py
  @commands.command(aliases=["claim"])
  @commands.cooldown(1, 86400, commands.BucketType.user)

  (some code here)


  @daily.error
  async def daily_error(self, ctx, error):
      if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
          embed = discord.Embed(
              title="You're on a cooldown!", color=discord.Color.blue())

          cd = round(error.retry_after)
          hours = str(cd // 3600)
          minutes = str(cd % 60)

          embed.add_field(
              name="\u200b",
              value=
              f"Slow down will ya?\n Wait for `{self.leadingZero(hours)}hours{self.leadingZero(minutes)}minutes`"
          )
          await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `@daily.error` will work perfectly fine. But I prefer using `on_command_error` because it will show you an error for every single command. It will be simpler just to do this

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        wait ctx.send("You're on cooldown.")
        return
    else:
        raise error
```

**Note: `raise error` will allow all the other errors to be printed in the terminal.**
But for this code it will only show in seconds, which isn't what you are looking for.

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="You're on a cooldown!", color=discord.Color.blue())

        cd = round(error.retry_after)
        hours = str(cd // 3600)
        minutes = str(cd % 60)

        embed.add_field(
            name="\u200b",
            value=
            f"Slow down will ya?\n Wait for `{hours} hours {minutes} minutes`"
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        raise error
```

Try that out, idk if that will work because you use cogs, and I do not.